# How to circumvent the infamous "unterminated string literal" error?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I attempted to load a simple HTML file into a canvas (browser = ff 3.66).

```
var canvas= document.getElementById('oneElement');
var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');

var img= new Image();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
img.src = 'data:text/html,&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 1&lt;td&gt;data 2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 3&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 4&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 5&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 6&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;
';
```

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have newlines inside your Javascript string -- which is not allowed.

You should remove those newlines, putting the string in only one line :

```
img.src = 'data:text/html,&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data1&lt;td&gt;data2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 3&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 4&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 5&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 6&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;';
```

Or, if you want to keep your code readable, a solution could be to use several small strings, and to use strings-concatenation :

```
img.src = 'data:text/html,&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 1&lt;td&gt;data 2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;' +
'&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 3&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 4&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;' +
'&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 5&gt;&lt;td&gt;data 6&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;' +
'&lt;/table&gt;';
```

Comment: Pascal, thank you.  with the strings-concatenation technique, I've made the syntax correct.  However, the function failed, that is, 
neither 
var tm = document.createElement('img');
tm.src = 'data:text/html,{html code here};

nor using a canvas with drawImage method then map
its src to the above similar HTML data call

would work with FF 3.66

I'm stuck.  What now?

Don

Answer (score 0):

Adding a '\' character at the end of each line before the line with the closing single quote should work.

```
img.src = 'here \
is an \
example';
```